# Как разделить (соединить) простые предложения?

Tags: пунктуация

Эти дивизии были уничтожены руками и оружием 18–19-летних участников многонациональных бригад(,) здесь были и татары, и русские...
Правильно ли стоит запятая в скобках (хочется добавить тире)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В этом месте может быть как **запятая** (присоединение уточнения, почему "многонациональные"), так и **тире** (частное ставится в соответствие более общему) или **точка** (для завершения сложного высказывания с последующим раскрытием того, о чем говорилось в его конце). Не подошла бы, однако, *точка с запятой* - как намеренное разделение (в рамках единого предложения) общего и конкретизирующего смыслов.

Более существенны стилистические недостатки.

1. "Здесь" употреблено при отсутствии каких-либо упоминаний о *месте* действия или о местонахождении говорящего - он должен бы тогда сам находиться, например, в музее боевой славы этой конкретной части и вести репортаж; даже если подразумевается какое-то удаленное место, то "там", а не "здесь". Заменить можно (после запятой) на "**в которых**", "**в них**" (после тире или точки).
2. "Руками и оружием": создается впечатление, что *не всегда* "оружием", что может вызвать в воображении читателя неэстетичные картины. Другая причина нежелательности "руками" в том, что это слово часто ассоциируется с устойчивым выражением "чужими руками" (или чьими-то - в случае манипуляции), Для патриотических текстов такое не подходит, я бы предложил "силами" (героическими усилиями и т. п.) или оставить просто "оружием".

Comment: Супер! Просил рубль - получил десять! Спасибо!

Answer (score 2):

Вариант правки:

***Эти дивизии были уничтожены совместными усилиями 18–19-летних участников многонациональных бригад — в них были и татары, и русские...***

Постановка тире вполне логична, это присоединительная конструкция со значением дополнительной информации.

С другой стороны, для постановки знаков препинания желательно видеть всё предложение, а иногда и контекст нужен.

**Примечание**

Сочетание "руками и оружием"  явно неудачно, но для чего автор его использовал? Я предполагаю, что это связано со структурой предложения —  с делением его на смысловые части произносительными паузами.

Сравнить: (1) Эти дивизии были уничтожены // оружием 18–19-летних участников многонациональных бригад... (2) Эти дивизии были уничтожены руками и оружием // 18–19-летних участников многонациональных бригад...

Положение произносительной паузы во втором варианте удобнее для чтения, поэтому желательно сохранить текстовый объем сочетания  "руками и оружием" при редактировании.